# Visio 2010 Add-in

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in, visio

I'm writing a Visio 2010 add-in.
I need to process the document and analyze all objects inside of it.

As first I got the current instance of Visio

```
        IVisio.Application app;

        object visioObject = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Visio.Application");
        app = visioObject as IVisio.Application;
```

Now, if

```
if (app.ActiveDocument != null)
```

How should I get all the elements of the active document?
How should I understand the type of the element I'm analyzing?
If this element is of type Entity (Object relational), how should I access all the columns definition?

Hope I cleared myself.

Thanks for eventual tips!

Answer (score 2):

I would start with the Visio 2010 Automation reference, found online at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861526.aspx

The Visio object model is quite a large beast, that takes some time to absorb and understand. But the classes are all documented on MSDN, so you should be able to find references, examples and probably even discussion forums up there.

A document basically consists of Master shapes, and Pages. These are both containers for Shape objects. And inside of shapes, you'll find the shapesheet with its Section, Row and Cell objects. Every Cell has a formula and a value.

There's more, too, but that might be enough to get you started.

Comment: Perhaps you have an example on how to get the first page of active document, cycle shapes and if of proper type get the columns?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't worked with Visio in C#, so I won't post an answer. But, I would guess the classes you're looking for are called IVisio.Document and IVisio.Page.  There is an ActiveDocument object on the Application object, and the first Page in that document is just Document.Pages(1). Every Page has a collection of Shapes, and like @DLRdave said, you can just loop through the different cell sections in the shapes.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of starting might be the following unit-test, that writes all shapes and names to the console:

```
[TestMethod]
public void testVisio()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application visioApp = null;
    try
    {
        //Create a new instance of Visio
        visioApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();
        // Show Visio
        visioApp.Visible = true;

        foreach (Page page in visioApp.ActiveDocument.Pages)
        {
            foreach (Shape shape in page.Shapes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Page {0}: Shape-Name: {1}", page.Name, shape.Name));
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //Close started application again
        visioApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(visioApp);
        visioApp = null;
    }
}
```

Of course you can replace the visioApp.ActiveDocument with the reference you already mentioned in your posting.

More information can be found on MSDN, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg617997.aspx and generally I recommend to just play around a bit, and you will find the objects required, e.g. shapes have cells where user-properties can be stored etc.
Or if not, you can ask a more specific question.